# Need help to create drag-able boxes with bootstrap and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create drag-able boxes with bootstrap jquery. My code is working. But I am not able to drag boxes from one div to another. Can you help? Here is the link: http://ewebturtles.com/task/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```js
$( function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
      } );
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        min-height: 20px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .ui-state-default {
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .ui-state-highlight {
        background: #eee;
    }
    #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Draggable</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="yellow panel-heading">Low Priority 1</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="yellow panel-heading">Low Priority 2</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="yellow panel-heading">Low Priority 3</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="yellow panel-heading">Low Priority 4</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">
        <div class="blue panel-heading">Low Priority 2.1</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">
        <div class="blue panel-heading">Low Priority 2.2</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">
        <div class="blue panel-heading">Low Priority 2.3</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">
        <div class="blue panel-heading">Low Priority 2.4</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content goes here....</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please check the link I have given. I am able to move the boxes within the first column. My Question is what if I want to move yellow box from one column to next column? Can you help me with this?

Comment: Thanks, Your code is working fine. But something is wrong when I am trying to embed it in my html. It is not working. Can you please have a look? http://ewebturtles.com/task/

Comment: You added `.download` in js files rename it remove `.download` from everywhere or put it on starting on the file name i.e  `script.download.js`

Comment: I didn't get you. I don't have any such file.

Comment: I am getting js errors in console that .sortable is not a function.

Comment: You can remove `jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js` and check it will work. don't forget to mark as correct. Thanks!